# Words library in android and ios

Tags: java, android, ios, swift

I was trying to find any information about device library of words, to check if string is actual word, when we're using keyboard autocorrect suppose to get words from somewhere, do anyone knows how to get access to this library?

Answer (score 0):

The UITextChecker class may be what you are looking for on iOS
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextchecker

Example implementation:

```
func isActualWord(wordToCheck: String) -> Bool {

    let textChecker = UITextChecker()
    let language = "en"
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: wordToCheck.utf16.count)
    let query = textChecker.rangeOfMisspelledWord(in: wordToCheck, range: range, startingAt: 0, wrap: false, language: language)
    return query.location == NSNotFound
}

isActualWord(wordToCheck: "Swift") //true
isActualWord(wordToCheck: "Swifty") //false

func suggestedWords(wordToCheck: String) -> [String]? {

    let textChecker = UITextChecker()
    let language = "en"
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: wordToCheck.utf16.count)
    let suggestedWords = textChecker.guesses(forWordRange: range, in: wordToCheck, language: language)
    return suggestedWords
}

suggestedWords(wordToCheck: "Swifty") // ["Swiftly", "Swifts", "Shifty", "Swift"]
```

Comment: works perfectly fine! thanks! do you know anything for android like that?

Comment: @NikitaFienberg No problem, glad it's what you needed.  Sorry, I can't help with Android.  Hopefully someone else may be able to help with that.